# Name change with Indian Tourist Visa on old Passport

Tags: visas, passports, tourist-visas

I have an old U.S. passport in my maiden name and valid Indian tourist visa.  I have now new U.S. passport with my new name.  Can I travel with both passports and name change certificate and be okay? or do I have to obtain a transfer of visa?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have a tourist visa for India if you have a US passport any more. India has this [tourist visa on arrival program](http://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/visa-on-arrival-in-india.29/) which was launched recently. It will cost you $60 and you can apply online 4 days prior to your departure.